# getting this error No route matches [GET] "/auth/facebook"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, omniauth

I m trying to user facebook login in my app and i am get the follow error.I and using Rails 4.I came across some other similar queries on stackover flow and tried their suggestions but it didnt help

No route matches [GET] "/auth/facebook"

```
 routes.rb
get 'auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#create'
  get 'auth/failure', to: redirect('/')
  get 'signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', as: 'signout'
```

initializers/omniauth.rb

```
OmniAuth.config.logger = Rails.logger

Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, FACEBOOK_KEY, FACEBOOK_SECRET, {:client_options => {:ssl => {:ca_file => Rails.root.join("cacert.pem").to_s}}}
end
```

Comment: At what point do you get it?

Comment: You could try using [this](https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook). It makes facebook login way easier

Comment: japed:I was getting it on clicking on the sign in button .Error is fixed now Rohit: I will try it.Thanks for suggesting

Comment: Sorry my bad.The error popped up again when i am running the app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your routes to the following:

```
get 'auth/:provider', to: 'sessions#create'
get 'auth/failure', to: redirect('/')
get 'signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', as: 'signout'
```

Comment: If i remove /callback then i get this error No route matches [GET] "/auth/facebook/callback"

Comment: IN my case it goes this way on routes:
  `devise_for :users, :path => 'user', :path_names => { :sign_in => "login"}, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" , :sessions => "users/sessions"}`
what shoud i do?